# Ajax POST request, parseerror

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make a web chat room, but when I send a post request to the server, with this code:

```
var line_count = 0;

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../scripts/engine.php',
    data: {'method': 'getMsg', 'line_count': line_count},
    dataType: 'json',
    error: function(request, error) {
        alert('Error: '+error);
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $.each(data.messages, function(i, val) {
            $('.messages').append(val);
        });
        line_count = data.srv_count;
    }
});
```

And:

```
<?php
$method = $_POST['method'];

switch($method) {
    case 'postMsg':
        $sender = $_SESSION['username'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];

        fwrite(fopen('chat.txt', 'a'), '<div class="time">[' . $time . ']</div><div class="nickname">' . $sender . '</div>' . $message . "\n");
        break;       
    case 'getMsg':
        $log = array();

        if(file_exists('chat.txt')) {
            $usr_count = $_POST['line_count'];
            $srv_msg = explode("\n", file('chat.txt'));
            $srv_count = count($srv_msg);

            $log['srv_count'] = $srv_count;

            if($usr_count < $srv_count) {
                $i = 0;

                while(list($key, $val) = each($srv_msg)) {
                    if ($i > $usr_count) {
                        $log['messages'][i] = $val;
                    }
                    $i = $i+1;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $log = false;
        }

        echo json_encode($log);
        break;
}
?>
```

Then I get this error message from ajax error function:
**"Error: parseerror"**. I checked the code many times, but I don't see where's the issue.
Thanks in advance

**Thanks everybody for the fast answers**
I checked returned value from the server, and I undertood it was a server-side problem. returnded value:



***Warning**:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in **X:\www\root\scripts\engine.php** on line **17**

{"srv_count":0}*


I just edited my code into:

```
                $usr_count = $_POST['line_count'];
                $srv_msg = explode("\n", file_get_contents('chat.txt'));
                $srv_count = count($srv_msg);

                $log['srv_count'] = $srv_count;

                if($usr_count < $srv_count) {
                    $i = 0;

                    while(list($key, $val) = each($srv_msg)) {
                        if ($i > $usr_count) {
                            $log['messages'][$i] = $val;
                        }
                        $i = $i+1;
                    }
                }
```

And now It's working fine.

Comment: Not sure it matters but remove the break from php.Also debug $log,make sure it was encode in valid json.

Comment: Thx I'll edit code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parseerror just means that you're not getting JSON back from the server. It could be PHP throwing an error and printing the error markup before the json.

check the console to see what is actually being returned from the server.

you may alos want to check `is_writable()` before attempting to write to a file. it could be a simple permissions issue.

Comment: message and time parameters is only if I set method to postMsg, but In code It's set to getMsg

Comment: still, we're all just guessing until you tell us what is actually returned by the server. someone may happen to guess correctly but you really should include all relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
print_r(json_encode($log));
```

to

```
echo json_encode($log);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks everybody for the fast answers**
I checked returned value from the server, and I undertood it was a server-side problem.
returnded value:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in <b>X:\www\root\scripts\engine.php</b> on line <b>17</b><br />
{"srv_count":0}
```